# No Screenshot with Cutycapt on https URLs

Tags: ssl, https, screen-capture

I'm using cutycapt to capture websites and generate thumbnails. (http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/)
It's very good, but on Websites with SSL there is no presentation of the website and the generated thumbnail is just white. It throws no error, it justs returns a white image, for example on: https://www.triboox.de

Does anyone have the same problem, and a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

It's likely cutycapt is getting invalid certificate errors. You can either fix this, or patch cutycapt to ignore ssl certificate errors:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2820272&group_id=230656&atid=1081397

Answer (score 2):

The newest version now sports a flag for ignoring certificate errors, which are getting in the way of your renders.

The new flag is "--insecure" as of 6/25/13

More info: http://sourceforge.net/p/cutycapt/code/9/

Comment: confirmed solution for duplicate issue on Ubuntu 13.04

Comment: It's 2017, and cutycapt Windows binary doesn't have this flag. Source code appears to have the flag, though, so it may be a matter of building from source.